# Automatic / apply inside manual date enter filed

Tags: date, calendar, range, picker

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7FYQZ.png)

input filed require format like dd/mm/yyyy.
input like this 22022022, am manually need to enter /

am enter value 22 after enter number 220, but expected 22/02/2000, automatically fill after 2 digit day and month